# Login Using Session

Tags: php, html, css

I have created a login page and i've written the php code for it in a separate file. After login, the page should be redirected to the particular user's report. Instead, it goes to a white blank page. What could be the bug?

Login.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link href="css1/login_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="css1/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="css1/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico"/>
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/favicon.png"/>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="login"> <!-- Login -->
    <h1> Login</h1>

    <form class="form" method="POST" action="loginaction.php">

      <p class="field">
        <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="id" required/>
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
      </p>

      <p class="field">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
        <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
      </p>

      <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>

      <p class="remember">
        <input type="checkbox" id="remember" name="remember" />
        <label for="remember"><span></span>Remember Me</label>
      </p>

      <p class="forgot">
        <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
      </p>

    </form>
  </div> <!--/ Login-->
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the php code for login,

loginaction.php

```
<?php
if( $_SESSION["logging"]&& $_SESSION["logged"])
{
     header("Location:view_restreport.php");
}
else {
    if(!$_SESSION["logging"])
    {  
    $_SESSION["logging"]=true;
    header("Location:index.php");
    }
       else if($_SESSION["logging"])
       {
         $number_of_rows=checkpass();
         if($number_of_rows>=1)
            {   
             $_SESSION[user]=$_GET[userlogin];
             $_SESSION['logged']=true;
             header("Location:view_restreport.php");
            }
        }
     }


function checkpass()
{
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$conn=  mysql_connect($servername,$username)or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("konjam_disc",$conn);
$sql="select * from users where name='$_GET[userlogin]' and password='$_GET[password]'";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
return  mysql_num_rows($result);
}
?>
```

What could be the silly mistake that I have made? I've been trying to figure it out for quite some time but haven't been able :-(
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to more learn still check how to make db connection and get form data

Comment: in loginaction, first php code line (after <?php) need to be session_start();

Comment: You should use mysqli or PDO instead of the deprecated extension mysql

Comment: white blank php page -> read the error log of your web server.

Comment: Things you should read into: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php http://php.net/manual/de/function.password-hash.php http://php.net/manual/de/class.mysqli.php

Comment: Your script is totally vulnerable to SQL injection. You should REALLY use PDO and prepared requests.

Comment: and add `exit();` after `header ('Location...');`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have session_start() on your PHP page, that should always be on the top when you are dealing with sessions. Also why don't you enable error reporting on your PHP page, or at least go take a look at the error log on your web server to see what error it gives you.

Answer (score 0):

Its good practice to escape php variables from queries like,

```
$sql="select * from users where name='".$_GET['userlogin']."' and password='".$_GET['password']."'";
```

Also dont forget `session_start();` in the begging of your php script.

Answer (score 0):

In your from you use the POST method. And in the query you use $_GET variable.
Also escaping variables is required.